# Data Dictionaries in memory in Java WebServices

Tags: java, web-services, memory, scope, data-dictionary

I have a Java WebService project and I want to use Data Dictionaries or HashMaps in memory. In other words I need to have a variable that can be accesed and written on it by every request. The reason of this is that I want to optimize my process and avoid making so many requests to the database.

In Java EE when using servlets I guess this could be solved with variables with context scope:

- read: getServletContext().getAttribute("name")
- written: getServletContext().setAttribute("name",value)

I'm looking for the equivalent in a web service project.

My first attempt was to save the variable in a File, but as I have hundreds of requests at the same time, I'm afraid I will get a too many open file error and the variable can't be saved as an object but it needs to be serialized.

I'm looking for the best alternative.

Comment: Have you ever heard of [Redis](https://redis.io/)?

Comment: Keep in mind that `HashMap` is not thread safe, so if you go that route make sure to either implement appropriate synchronization/locking, or use a thread-safe `Collection`, such as `ConcurrentHashMap`, `Hashtable`, or `Collections.SynchronizedMap`.  I like the suggestion of @ElliottFrisch to investigate Redis.  Perhaps this article will help you: https://dzone.com/articles/database-caching-with-redis-and-java